# Aplicar estilo si contiene cierto texto en CSS

Tags: css

Estoy trasteando con CSS en mi portal web, donde tras mucho probar he conseguido aplicar estilos a los links externos con la siguiente regla sin necesidad de incluir condicionales y replaces en mi `functions.php`:

```css
.entry-content a:not( [href*='miweb.com/'] ):after{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: url('https://api.iconify.design/fa-solid:sign-out-alt.svg?height=16');
}
```

Ahora, me gustaría seguir aplicando estilos a los enlaces de correo para ponerles un icono de email.

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a CSS que aplique una nueva regla cuando contenga `mailto:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría funcionar lo siguiente:

CSS:

```
a[href^="mailto:"]:after{ 
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: url('https://api.iconify.design/fa-solid:sign-out-alt.svg height=16');
}
```

Comment: Gracias Victor. El editor me marca el uso de ```href^=``` como lento... ¿Esto tiene alguna repercusión negativa? ¿O es tan solo un aviso?

Comment: Realmente no. Me imagino que es porque el "content" hace la petición al icono de una URL externa.

Comment: Entiendo... La solución a poner el ```content``` con una url externa es porque no consigo mostrar ese icono con el código unicode, me pinta un cuadrado blanco.

Comment: Podrias colocar SVG directamente. Ya sea que los subos a una carpeta de tu proyecto y los llames.

Esta web podria ayudarte
[materialdesignicons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: No había caído en colocar el .svg directamente en mi web y lo llame desde ahí... ¡¡Thanks!!